# Program * does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods, project

I've had the homework of making a program, made up of 2 seperate projects, containing classes for a Square, Rectangle, and a Parallelepiped, and to be able to calculate their areas. I think I've done everything correctly and connected the projects, but I keep getting this error message when I try to compile the code:

> Program * does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

Both of my projects have Static Main methods.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Please provide relevant code in text form and not as images.

Comment: what is the program type?

Comment: There are a lot of previously asked question that are similar to this on the RHS of the screen. Have you checked them to see if any fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is not clear due to the image, but what I see wrong here is that, Main has been spelled incorrectly,

You have written s

```
MaIN(string[] args)
```

its should be

```
 Main(string[] args)
```

*see the capitalization.

Please make it a practice to post codes rather than posting images.

Answer (score -1):

Make your Main method inside a Program class. eg:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first picture he have it in this format but still getting an error

Comment: Not in the third one

Comment: Having main method in program class is not required. It can be any class.